# Point2D Iterator Objects do not next() method. How do I iterate through a list of these objects then?

Tags: java, swing, iterator

This is a Java Swing Application.

When I create an ArrayList list of objects and then wish to iterate through them, I can create an iterator however no next() method for the iterator object exists for me to even iterate through. It contains all the other methods one would expect with the Iterator object except this one. Anyone know how to iterate through my ArrayList

To answer a couple of questions outright. I am using Point2D because it stores doubles which I need as I am animating an object across a screen. I need to use Iterators because I may be removing certain points during iteration.

Here is code per request. I have elected to greatly simplify the code since what I have is a bit more than this. To see what I am seeing simply create an ArrayList of Point2D objects

```
ArrayList<Point2D> pPoints = new ArrayList();
pPoints.add(new Point2D(45.5, 67.7));
pPoints.add(new Point2D(32.13, 123.5));
pPoints.add(new Point2D(56.0, 56.0));

for (Iterator<Point2D> PointIt = pPoints.iterator(); PointIt.hasNext();) {

     PointIt.next(); // This next method doesn't exist. 
}
```

Comment: The iterator that you get from the `ArrayList` should have a `next()` method. Do you have any code so we can reproduce this error?

Comment: I have added code per request. I am using the ArrayList iterator. My other arraylist iterators have next(). This particular one doesn't for some reason.

Comment: Wait.. in creating the code above I just realized I could have been loading the wrong library. NetBeans tells you to load a library if it doesn't exist, I may have loaded the wrong one. (Not the awt library). In loading the awt library this error is fixed.

Comment: I was thinking that may have been the case. Maybe you used the `Iterator` from Java's `HTMLDocument` instead?

Comment: I might have a problem with using Point2D anyways because it's an abstract class and it's creating an lot of syntax errors.

Comment: Yeah, I just assumed that you wrote some class that inherits it and fed that into the arraylist. Fixing that first would probably be the best plan of attack.